# Quiero agregar una variable como clave en un objeto JSON

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Tengo un objeto en el cual quiero que se implemente el nombre de un usuario y su conexión cuando este se una, pero si utilizo "conexiones.player.name = player.conn" me da eror, pero de todas formas guardandolo en una variable, al querer usarla lo toma como un string.
¿Que puedo hacer?

```
let conexiones = {};

r.onPlayerJoin = function (player) {
  let playerName = player.name;
  conexiones.playerName = player.conn;
  console.log(conexiones);
}
```

Entonces al hacer un console.log de conexiones, el resultado esperado sería:
{ user1: "conn1", user2: "conn2", user3: "conn3" }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si el resultado esperado es

`{ user1: "conn1", user2: "conn2", user3: "conn3" }`

Es decir `playerName : conexión`

Tienes que hacerlo de esta manera:

```
let conexiones = {};

r.onPlayerJoin = function (player) {
  conexiones[player.name] = player.conn;
  //console.log(conexiones);
}
```

Comment: Lo estoy testeando en mi código para ver si recibo el resultado esperado, muchas gracias por la contribución y por la aclaración!

Comment: Funciona perfecto!

Comment: Si agrego 2 veces el mismo jugador pero con distinta conexion la conexion solo se sobreescribirá?

Comment: @Espulito: Sí, pues estarás sobreescribiendo el valor de la clave del player.name

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias por la ayuda! Me había hecho tremendo lío y no podía encontrar una solución.

Comment: @masterguru Yo iba a estar un mes solamente y si no es porque te pusiste las pilas en Octubre ya me habría marchado (como verás yo también soy competitivo :P ). Espero te vaya fabuloso en tus nuevos retos!!!